# Keras: How to slice tensor using information from another tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, slice

I am trying to implement a custom loss function and have come across this problem. The custom loss function will look something like this:

```python
def customLoss(z):
    y_pred = z[0] 
    y_true = z[1]
    features = z[2] 
    ...
    return loss
```

In my situation, `y_pred` and `y_true` are actually greyscale images. The features contained in `z[2]` consists of a pair of locations `(x,y)` where I would like to compare `y_pred` and `y_true`. These locations depend on the input training sample, so when defining the model they are passed as inputs. So my question is: how do I use the tensor `features` to index into the tensors `y_pred` and `y_true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Tensorflow as backend, [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) could do the trick (Keras doesn't have an exact equivalent yet as far as I can tell):

```python
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def customLoss(z):
    y_pred = z[0]
    y_true = z[1]
    features = z[2]

    # Gathering values according to 2D indices:
    y_true_feat = tf.gather_nd(y_true, features)
    y_pred_feat = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, features)

    # Computing loss (to be replaced):
    loss = K.abs(y_true_feat - y_pred_feat)
    return loss

# Demonstration:
y_true = K.constant([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]])
y_pred = K.constant([[[0, 0, -1], [1, 1, 1]], [[0, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]])
coords = K.constant([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype="int64")

loss = customLoss([y_pred, y_true, coords])

tf_session = K.get_session()
print(loss.eval(session=tf_session))
# [[ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 2.  0.  2.]]
```

---

*Note 1:* Keras however has [`K.gather()`](https://keras.io/backend/#gather) which only works for 1D indices. If you want to use native Keras only, you could still flatten your matrices and indices, to apply this method:

```python
def customLoss(z):
    y_pred = z[0]
    y_true = z[1]
    features = z[2]

    y_shape = K.shape(y_true)
    y_dims = K.int_shape(y_shape)[0]

    # Reshaping y_pred & y_true from (N, M, ...) to (N*M, ...):
    y_shape_flat = [y_shape[0] * y_shape[1]] + [-1] * (y_dims - 2)
    y_true_flat = K.reshape(y_true, y_shape_flat)
    y_pred_flat = K.reshape(y_pred, y_shape_flat)

    # Transforming accordingly the 2D coordinates in 1D ones:
    features_flat = features[0] * y_shape[1] + features[1]

    # Gathering the values:
    y_true_feat = K.gather(y_true_flat, features_flat)
    y_pred_feat = K.gather(y_pred_flat, features_flat)

    # Computing loss (to be replaced):
    loss = K.abs(y_true_feat - y_pred_feat)
    return loss
```

*Note 2:* To answer your question in comment, slicing can be done in a numpy-way with Tensorflow as backend:

```python
x = K.constant([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])
sess = K.get_session()

# When it comes to slicing, TF tensors work as numpy arrays:
slice = x[0, 0:2, 0:3]
print(slice.eval(session=sess))
# [[ 0.  1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.  5.]]

# This also works if your indices are tensors (TF will call tf.slice() below):
coords_range_per_dim = K.constant([[0, 2], [0, 3]], dtype="int32")
slice = x[0,
          coords_range_per_dim[0][0]:coords_range_per_dim[0][1],
          coords_range_per_dim[1][0]:coords_range_per_dim[1][1]
         ]
print(slice.eval(session=sess))
# [[ 0.  1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.  5.]]
```

Comment: `tf.gather_nd()` sounds very close to what I want. Is it possible to extract some sub-tensor that doesn't run the full range of values? For example, what operation would be equivalent to something like `y_true[0, 0:2, 0:2]` in your example?

Comment: Yes, slicing can be done rather easily with TF as backend. I updated my answer to show examples.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused: if you can slice directly as in your edited answer, then what's the point of `tf.gather_nd()`?

Comment: If your `features` contain a list of 2D coordinates, you can retrieve the corresponding values at once with `tf.gather_nd()`. If your `features` is a single 2D coordinate or coordinate range, you can more simply use the shorter numpy-like notation.